# Button not correct colour

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, controls

I have a WPF usercontrol with a Button. I've replicated the standard button shading of `System.Windows.Media.LinearGradientBrush` by `Extract Value to Resource` to get sight of the default setup in resources

I've then copied the resource but substituted the default colours to the ones I want

```
    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1">
        <GradientStop Color="#FFF3F3F3" Offset="0" />
        <GradientStop Color="#FFEBEBEB" Offset="0.5" />
        <GradientStop Color="#FFDDDDDD" Offset="0.5" />
        <GradientStop Color="#FFCDCDCD" Offset="1" />
    </LinearGradientBrush>
```

I've then deleted the resource so my full XAML looks like

```
<UserControl x:Class="Project.Detail"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="30" d:DesignWidth="800" BorderBrush="#FF5380E7" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" >
    <Grid Height="30" Width="800">
        <Button Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="254,0,0,0" Name="bOption3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" Click="bOption_Click" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="10" FontStretch="SemiCondensed">
            <Button.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFD2DEF9" Offset="0" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFC5D4F7" Offset="0.5" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFAEC3F4" Offset="0.5" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF8FACF0" Offset="1" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

In the designer I see the colours I've set with the correct gradient but when I build and run the buttons are the default grey colour.

Can anyone tell what I am doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

I want to retain the default button style except the initial state background I want my own colours. I've now tried adding specific resources for the background

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="NewBackground" EndPoint="0,1">
        <GradientStop Color="#FFD2DEF9" Offset="0" />
        <GradientStop Color="#FFC5D4F7" Offset="0.5" />
        <GradientStop Color="#FFAEC3F4" Offset="0.5" />
        <GradientStop Color="#FF8FACF0" Offset="1" />
    </LinearGradientBrush>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

and then adding

```
<Button Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="360,0,0,0"  Background="{StaticResource NewBackground}">
```

Again in the designer I can see the colour being applied but when the app runs it has the default grey colour at all times.

***Button in design mode***

[image]

***Button in App***

[image]

I now have a few questions

1. Is there a simple way to change just 1 property of the default button rather than create complete new style?
2. If I have to recreate a full style where can I access all the default properties to make it look the same?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using a UserControl? Could you not style the button?

Comment: The usercontrol allows me to setup a custom layout that are stacked on top of each other.

Comment: I have tried your code and i can see the colours everything is correct. Except when u press the button its changes, But that is because the button has another state and is using another template.

Comment: If I want the button to behave the same way in different states, except have the initial colours that are different - how do I find all the properties to style it?

Comment: You would have to override the default template of a button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes you can for certain properties and it depends. Say if you want to change the FontSize, FontFamily, FontSize, FontStretch, etc. There are some attach properties provided by WPF to override it e.g.

   `<Grid TextElement.FontFamily=""/>` 
   or `<Button TextElement.FontFamily=""/>`
2. You can try going to Expression blend and extract the default template of WPF controls. Customize the templates from there.

More info can be found [here](http://www.shafqatahmed.com/2009/01/wpf-kid-stuff-extracting-a-control-template.html)